# Confusion about array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

What does this mean in C:

```
char strings[USHRT_MAX][50];
```

Is it creating a jagged array of characters called strings?

Comment: Study some basics before posting simple questions like this.

Answer (score 5):

No, the above does not create a jagged array of strings. It creates an array of characters with two dimensions, capable of storing up to `USHRT_MAX` C strings of up to 49 characters in length (the fiftieth `char` is used for the `'\0'` terminator).

A jagged array declaration would look like this:

```
char *strings[USHRT_MAX];
```

With an array of pointers you would need to allocate memory for the individual strings, but the strings could differ in length from one element to the other. Your array, on the other hand, has all memory allocated, but it places a limit on the length of strings, and has a potential of using more memory than you need to store shorter strings.

Comment: Ah, ok thankyou. So I presume if USHRT_MAX is greater than 49 charachters it will overwrite adjacent stack locations.

Comment: @user2153547 If you try accessing `strings[stringNumber][charNumber]`, and `stringNumber` is greater than or equal to `USHRT_MAX`, your program may crash. If the `stringNumber` is less than `USHRT_MAX`, but `charIndex` is greater than 49, your program may also crash. Whether or not it is going to override an adjacent stack location is implementation specific: `strings` could be in the static memory, or there may not be a stack at all.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char strings[USHRT_MAX][50];
```

Just provides a 2 dimensional array of characters. The size is `USHRT_MAX` by 50. This is not a  jagged array, a jagged array is one which has various length rows, conceptually this would be:

```
strings[0] = ['a']['\0']
strings[1] = ['j']['a']['g']['\0']
strings[2] = ['a']['r']['r']['a']['y']['\0']
```

Where as yours is more like:

```
strings[0] = ['a']['\0'][ ][ ][ ][ ]
strings[1] = ['j']['a']['g']['\0'][ ][ ]
strings[2] = ['a']['r']['r']['a']['y']['\0']
```

Note in the second example they all have the same number of elements in each row, but not all elements are filled.